# Solana Pay for Python

Tags: python, solana-pay

How can do about using the existing Solana pay functionality with python? Looking at the documentation, I see that we have .js library available. Is there a way I can utilize the existing functionality using python even if it means creating my own Solana pay python wrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a library out there that attempts to port the functionality over to Python, I don't know how well this library works or if it has full coverage but it should give you a good reference of how it can be done.

https://github.com/itayb1/solana-pay-py

Answer (score 1):

Hey Solana Pay is a really Simple Library that implements some bare-bone functions for creating QR codes and verifying Transactions. If you check the source code you will find out it's not that big. It's the underlying Specification that gives it power.